# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout don't have chains that you can drag

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains, androidx

I'm using **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout** in my layout and it does not show the chains, also I can't drag any widgets. I just type the constraints that I want to use.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"/>
```

here's a sample screen shot for androidx constraintLayout:
[androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efNVL.png)

but when I tried switching back to : **android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout** it i can see it

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"/>
```

here's a sample screen shot for support constraintLayout: 
[android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vT5q.png)

is this a bug or something?

### edit:

my current solution is to switch from:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

but this does not solve my problem cause I don't want to use support.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem until I realized that I should use the Canary version to solve it.
after installing Canary version beside stable version, open the project and now you can use this implementation:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Keep in mind that you may need to do the following:

- clean project
- rebuild
- invalidate caches/restart

My problem solved with this method.

Comment: I'm using canary version when I've encountered this. I've realized that maybe because it's in the 'CANARY' version where we encounter more bugs, and where bugs can autofix itself. 

I updated my Android Studio to 3.3 Canary 6 and now its working

Comment: Clean project is all I had to do

Answer (score 14):

if you are using latest Android update 3.3.3 then migrate to Android x from support constraint layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For getting this also change gradle:

implementation  com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3

to

implementation  androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3